# Show validation message without shifting other elements in the page

Tags: javascript, validation

I have two text boxes as required fields one on top of the another. How can I show the "Field is required" message underneath the text box without causing the element below to be shifted down?

[image]

When the "Origin does not exist" message is show the "Destination" text box moves down a little. How can I prevent the "Destination" text box from moving when displaying error messages? I would prefer to do this with Javascript.

[image]

This is what I have tried and I just can't figure it how to do this.
The validateStop() method creates a "div" element and inserts the error message in it.

```
function validateStop(stopNode){
        var inputStop = $.trim(stopNode.value);
        createSiblingNodeFor(stopNode);//creates div node to display error msg. 
        if(isEmpty(inputStop)){
            showInputRequiredMsg(stopNode.id, stopNode); 
            return false;
        }
}


<td>
    <input id="origin" type="text" onblur="validateStop(this)" value="" name="origin">
    <div id="originvalidationResult" style="color: red;">origin is required.</div>
</td>
```

**EDITS:**

I added "position:absolute" to the div element and this is what happened in IE8 although it seems to be working in firefox. We are required to use IE8:

```
In IE8:
```

[image]

```
In Firefox:
```

[image]

Comment: Javascript != Java :)

Comment: this is not something you need to handle in javascript as it would require a small amount of styling. regardless, you will be altering the css of the text. either you can set it in a css file or change it in javascript. easiest way (particularly if you're not already using jquery) would be to give it absolute positioning in your css

Comment: @iAmClownShoe I tried the position: absolute and it seems to be working in firefox but not in IE. In IE it overlaps with the element next to it. You can look at the edit I posted above for more info. Thank you.

Comment: im at a loss here. I told you to use position:absolute i don't know where you came up with position:block from but that is not a valid css property. maybe you meant display:block but if that's the case then nothing will have happened because things positioned absolutely are automatically given display:block as it's the only way that makes sense to display elements out of the normal flow the document. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: If you are having css problems then I suggest taking some time to learn css basics as you will run into far more annoying problems than this. It seems to me that you are wholly unfamiliar with front end web development using javascript/css and if that's the case, maybe it would be more beneficial to start with basics and tutorials. Problems like this won't happen with some very basic knowledge of css. I can appreciate that you may be trying to learn but while we are all here to help, we are not here to do it for you.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe I'm sorry. I meant to say I did "position: absolute". Thanks I'll take a look at some CSS tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To have things go predictably, make sure that the parent `<td>` has enough height (apply some height style ) when the page renders. I'd also specify height of the input field and give the error div height as well. Tweak the spacing until nothing shifts.